The archive did not include a dSYM for the Flutter.framework with the UUIDs
I'm new to Flutter iOS development. Trying to publish an app on the Apple app store. But after building the archive, when I try to distribute or validate the app, Xcode keeps me showing

The archive did not include a dSYM for the Flutter.framework with the UUIDs [4C4C-5555--****-*****45CD327]. Ensure that the archive's dSYM folder includes a DWARF file for Flutter.framework with the expected UUIDs.


How can I overcome this?

Did you try what's here? If so, then edit your answer, link the other question and what you tried. That way readers know you tried similar questions before opening a new question

I began to get the exact same error on Xcode16, but the upload actually succeeded (found on App Store Connect).

Same for XCode 16

To solve this problem you just need to update the flutter version

To retrieve the dSYM file for your Flutter app in Xcode, follow these steps:

Open Xcode:

Start Xcode and go to your project.


Create an Archive:

Click on Product in the top menu.
Select Archive. This will build and archive your app.


Access Archives:

Once the archiving process is complete, the Organizer window will open.
You’ll see a list of archives for your app. Right-click on the archive
you want to access.


Show in Finder:

From the right-click menu, select Show in Finder. This will open a Finder
window showing the archived files.


Locate the .xcarchive File:

You should see a file with the extension .xcarchive (it’ll have your app
name). Right-click on this file.


Show Package Contents:

Select Show Package Contents from the right-click menu. This will open a new window showing the internal structure of the archive.


Find the dSYMs Folder:

Look for a folder named dSYMs inside the package contents. Open this
folder.


Get the .dSYM File:

Inside the dSYMs folder, you’ll find the .dSYM file you need. You can
copy it from here for your distribution needs




I followed the steps up to step 7, but inside my dSYMs folder, I couldn't find the .dSYM file.

I just upgraded my flutter and the warning is gone.
I just did "flutter upgrade" in my vscode terminal.

I have the same issue, but I found a temporary solution.
Vs code:
flutter build ios --no-codesign

get path like - /build/.../runner.app/
Flutter.framework floder inside run below code:
dsymutil Flutter -o Flutter.framework.dSYM

get (Flutter.framework.dSYM) file to paste into the xcode => archive => package content => DSYMs floder
Revalidate the file pasted in the same build
